# setting the value of a date time sharepoint field in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have the following scenario:

I want to capture the selected date/time by end user from a calendar view of a sharepoint list
I am working on a script that would get these values as selectedDate & selectedTime

Now, how do I set these selected value to my sharepoint date time attribute ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear...

If you want to get the value of a Date field from a List, you can use [SharepointPlus get() function](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.list.html#.get) with [toDate()](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.html#.toDate). Below is an example:

```
// in a classic Calendar list in Sharepoint, the date field is called "Start Time", that becomes "Start_x0020_Time" for the internal name
$SP().list("Calendar").get({fields:"Start_x0020_Time"}, function(data) {
  for (var i=data.length; i--;) {
    // $SP().toDate(data[i].getAttribute("Start_x0020_Time")) will return a JavaScript Date object
  }
})
```

And you can use [add()](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.list.html#.add) or [update()](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.list.html#.update) to set the value. Example:

```
var today = new Date(); // JavaScript Date object
$SP().list("Calendar").update({ID:1, Start_x0020_Time:$SP().toSPDate(today)})
```